# android database error fatal exception:main

Tags: android, database

As am a beginer in android .I got stuck at database program.I checked all the program many times and icouldnt find out a solution.while on click my application is onfortunately stopping. i am getting the following error in logcat..

```
<`10-20 13:03:10.910: E/SQLiteLog(982): (1) near "fromFRIENDSwhereCITYNOT": syntax error
10-20 13:03:10.930: D/AndroidRuntime(982): Shutting down VM
10-20 13:03:10.930: W/dalvikvm(982): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  ... 11 more
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "fromFRIENDSwhereCITYNOT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * fromFRIENDSwhereCITYNOT IN(?,?)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  at com.example.database.DatabaseActivity.clicked(DatabaseActivity.java:65)
10-20 13:03:11.120: E/AndroidRuntime(982):  ... 14 more
`>
```

my activity is.....

```
     <`package com.example.database;

import com.example.database.Contractclass.Friends;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    String[]names={"sum","chan","hop","nav"};
    String[] cities={"mpl","kpm","vignr","nrml"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_database);
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.database, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void clicked(View v)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db;

        switch (((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1)).getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.radio0:
            db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            db.beginTransaction();
            for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
            {
                cv.put(Friends.COLUMN_NAME1, names[i]);
                cv.put(Friends.COLUMN_NAME2, cities[i]);
                db.insert(Friends.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
            }
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;
        case R.id.radio1:
            TextView data=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            data.setText("");
            db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Toast.makeText(this, "12", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String sql="select * from "+Friends.TABLE_NAME+" where "+Friends.COLUMN_NAME2+" NOT IN(?,?)";
            String[] removecities={"mpl","kpm"};
            Cursor selecteddata=db.rawQuery(sql, removecities);
            if(selecteddata.getCount()==0)
            {
                data.setText("your are stupid");
            }
            else
            {
                while (selecteddata.moveToNext()) {
                    data.append(selecteddata.getString(selecteddata.getColumnIndex(Friends.COLUMN_NAME1))+","+selecteddata.getString(selecteddata.getColumnIndex(Friends.COLUMN_NAME2))+"\n");



                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radio2:
            db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(Friends.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
            db.close();
            break;

        case R.id.radio3:
            db=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv2=new ContentValues();
            for(int i=0;i<cities.length;i++)
            {
                cv2.put(Friends.COLUMN_NAME2, (cities[i]+i));
                db.update(Friends.TABLE_NAME, cv2, Friends.COLUMN_NAME2+"=?", new String[]{cities[i]});

            }
            db.close();
            break;
        }
    }

}
`>
```

my contract class....

```
<`package com.example.database;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
public class Contractclass {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=3;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Database.db";
     public static abstract class Friends implements BaseColumns{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="FRIENDS";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME1="NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME2="CITY";
    }
}
`>
```

my databasehelper class is......

```
<
`
{
package com.example.database;
import com.example.database.Contractclass.Friends;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,  Contractclass.DATABASE_NAME , null, Contractclass.DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
//  public DatabaseHelper(DatabaseActivity databaseActivity) {
//      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
//      super(null, null, null, 0);
//  }
    public static final String CREATE_DB="CREATE TABLE"+Friends.TABLE_NAME+"("+Friends._ID+"INTEGER"+" PRIMARYKEY,"+Friends.COLUMN_NAME1+"TEXT,"+Friends.COLUMN_NAME2+"TEXT)";
    public static final String DROP_DB="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+Friends.TABLE_NAME;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DB);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            db.execSQL(DROP_DB);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        onCreate(db);
        }


}
`>
```

Comment: You missed spaces at `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: even after I made changes it is showing error .

Comment: Did you try escape sequence? ie, `"select * from \t"+Friends.TABLE_NAME+"\t where \t"+....`

Comment: yeah tried but didn't worked..please i need solutin

Comment: You have an extra level of abstraction using `static abstract class Friends`. Is it necessary? Isn't it simpler to call `Contractclass.TABLE_NAME' by removing that abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

Your error log shows that you're passing a query "fromFRIENDSwhereCITY" without no space put in between the terms. It must be "from FRIENDS where CITY", so naturally sqlite will raise a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The Main cause for the error is, during the first Execution itself a table (FRIENDS) is created in memory even though Activity stopped.The solution is change Database Version in Contract Class to any higher value than present one.Then on execution onUpgrade() method is called and new table(FRIENDS) will be created and execute without abrupt stopping of Activity.